# Regarding SQL Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-pivot

Hi I have been trying to do a PIVOT for the following data.

```
LeaseId | ColumnHeader  | UIPayments | UIResidual
-------------------------------------------------
25573   | 2019-05-01    | 0.0000     | 0.0000    
25573   | 2019-06-01    | 0.0000     | 0.0000    
25573   | 2019-07-01    | 0.0000     | 0.0000    
25573   | 2019-08-01    | 0.0000     | 0.0000    
25573   | 2019-09-01    | 0.0000     | 0.0000    
25573   | 2019-10-01    | 0.0000     | 0.0000
```

The result dataset should look like:

```
LeaseId |Details    | 2019-05-01| 2019-06-01|2019-07-01 |2019-08-01
-----------------------------------------------------------------                
25573   |UIPayments |5.0000     |5.0000     |5.0000     |5.0000

25573   |UIResidual |1.0000     |1.0000     |1.0000     |1.0000
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

The query I have tried so far:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',[' + CAST(DATEFROMPARTS(#TempMonths.y, #TempMonths.m, '01') AS VARCHAR(20)) + ']'
                from #TempMonths
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT LeaseID, UIPayments, UIResidual, PVResidual, PVPayments, NetInvestment,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            SELECT * FROM #TmpDetails
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            UIPayments, UIResidual, PVResidual, PVPayments, NetInvestment
            for ColumnHeader in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '
```

I really don't know if this is even a valid query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: what's the logic, what have you tried so far..?

Comment: Do you ***know*** for ***certain*** that these are the final columns you want/need?  Or do you want to make the columns defined by the values present in the data?  If so, that's almost never a good thing to do in SQL: it's messy and breaches most SQL patterns *(it's normally best to keep formatting in a "presentation layer", such as the application that you do your reporting in.  If you explain exactly how you want to use this data, and where, we can probably help you with a more robust/appropriate solution to you actual needs.)*

Comment: I am using SQL. I am not able to get the logic for this, but I will post what I have done so far below. Regarding the columns, it is dynamic. Based on the Input date the columns will each month for the next 2 years. i.e. If input date is Jan 1st 2018, Then columns will be Jan 1 2018, Feb 1 2018, ... Jan 1 2020.

Comment: @Ashwath - As per my preceding comment.  Wanting to do this normally breaches established SQL patterns.  There is no native SQL that can do it.  What you have to do is read the table, get a list of the columns, use that to programatically generate a new sql statement and run that.  That level of complexity and overhead is a very strong indicator you're walking down the wrong path.  Please may I ask again; If you explain exactly how you want to use this data, and where, we can probably help you with a more robust/appropriate solution to you actual needs.

Comment: @MatBailie I understand your point. And yes I am writing a SP for creating a Report using Crystal Reports tool. The specification is to print the Amount values i.e.  UIPayments, UIResidual, .. many more as Rows with the Months as columns headers. If I am able to achieve this, then I will be able to use grouping in Crystal Reports and display the values as they expect.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggregation should work in almost any database:

```
select LeaseId, 'UIPayments' as details,
       sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-05-01' then UIPayments else 0 end) as val_20190501,
       sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-06-01' then UIPayments else 0 end) as val_20190601,
       sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-07-01' then UIPayments else 0 end) as val_20190701,
       sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-08-01' then UIPayments else 0 end) as val_20190801
from t
group by LeaseId
union all
select LeaseId, 'UIResidual' as details,
       sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-05-01' then UIResidual else 0 end) as val_20190501,
       sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-06-01' then UIResidual else 0 end) as val_20190601,
       sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-07-01' then UIResidual else 0 end) as val_20190701,
       sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-08-01' then UIResidual else 0 end) as val_20190801
from t
group by LeaseId;
```

I guess the trick is that you need to handle each column separately.  In many databases, you could do this using a lateral join, rather than `union all`.

Comment: But the columns are dynamic in my case. How would I be able to use this approach?

Comment: You can make this ` sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-05-01' then UIPayments else 0 end) as val_20190501,
       sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-06-01' then UIPayments else 0 end) as val_20190601,
       sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-07-01' then UIPayments else 0 end) as val_20190701,
       sum(case when ColumnHeader = '2019-08-01' then UIPayments else 0 end) as val_20190801` this part dynamic using **java or .net** code.